# Linq-to-SQL slow stored procedure when using date parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

Any help on this one would be greatly appreciated!

I'm using Linq-to-SQL to call a stored procedure in SQL Server. The stored procedure has 3 parameters; int, datetime, datetime.

When I call this from Linq-to-SQL in my ASP.NET MVC application, it is agonisingly slow and can timeout. However when I call the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, it returns the results in a second or so.

I removed the dates as parameters and hardcoded the sames dates into the procedure and called it from my web app and it runs as it should. Put those date params back in and it hangs. Any ideas? Issue with date formats etc?

Not really doing anything fancy here..

C#

```
public List<Sales> GetSales(int StoreId, DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo)
{
    using (AppDataContext ctx = new AppDataContext())
    {
        var result = ctx.sp_GetSales(id, dateFrom, dateTo).ToList(); 

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            // handle data returned
        }
    }
}
```

All dates are type `DateTime`. I don't think it is the stored procedure, as I said, it works perfectly when I hard code the dates. Perhaps something to do with mapping Linq-to-SQL with the stored procedure? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Can you please post the **table structure** (including any indexes you might have on that table) and the code of your stored procedure?

Comment: You may want to consider running SQL Profiler and see how LINQ generates the SQL query that executes your stored procedure. It might provide some help

Comment: Hi Marc,  I don't have access to the source code right now but will update the post in the morning (Sydney time) when I do.

Comment: Without access to the relevant source code, really cannot tell you what the issue may be. I'd actually like to see the `sp_GetSales` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a long shot, but I think I've seen this before with dates. I think the issue I saw was something to do with [parameter sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/), but it never quite added up as SQL Server seemed to manage to generate a query which was orders of magnitude worse than **any** parameter that had ever been supplied to the query.

It was some time ago, however if I recall correctly doing the following in the stored procedure fixed the issue:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test
    @Param1 DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Param1_Copy DATETIME = @Param1

    -- Use @Param1_Copy instead of @Param1
END
```

For some reason "Copying" the parameter in this way seemed to prevent the issue. Potentially using `WITH RECOMPILE` or other parameter sniffing solutions might work, I can't remember.

If this doesn't solve your issue then I recommend using SQL Server Profiler to capture a SQL trace of the exact SQL statements executed by your application, and try running that exact statement in SQL Server Management Studio to see if that reproduces the poor performance - even quite subtle differences in the way in which a procedure is executed can cause differences. I also believe SQL Server Management Studio uses different [Session Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sessionproperty-transact-sql) (i.e. `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` etc...) to .Net. Its possible that one of those settings is the reason why you can't reproduce this in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick Justin! Just copied the date params and used them through the procedure and it is running just as quick as it would if i ran it in the Management Studio. I must read up on it to understand the science behind it.  Many thanks!

Comment: @MichaelB If you figure it out, please let me know!